Topology of uniform convergence as right adjoint
Let $I$ be a set and consider the adjunction  $I\times(-):\mathrm{Set}\rightleftarrows\mathrm{Set}:(-)^{\times I}$, where $I\times X$ is the cartesian product and $X^{\times I}$ is the set of the functions $I\to X$.
Question: this adjunction can be lifted to an adjunction $\mathrm{Top}\rightleftarrows\mathrm{Top}$ when $I$ is endowed with the discrete topology?
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Top}@>>>\mathrm{Top}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathrm{Set}@>>I\times(-)>\mathrm{Set}
\end{CD}\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Top}@<<<\mathrm{Top}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathrm{Set}@<<(-)^{\times I}<\mathrm{Set}
\end{CD}$$
I think that the answer is affirmative by tauth lift theorem.
When $X$ is an uniform space, then I think that $X^{\times I}$ has the uniformity of uniform convergence, that's its entourages are (up to a bijection) of the form $U^{\times I}$ for $U$ running over the entourages of $X$.
But what's the topology on $X^{\times I}$ when $X$ is a topological (not necessarily uniform) space? There exists a name for this topology?

For topological spaces, the best analogue of the topology of uniform convergence is the compact-open topology (the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets). I think if $I$ is discrete, the compact-open topology on $X^{\times I}$ agrees with the product topology.

In fact, I think that when $I$ is discrete, we have $\coprod\limits_I X \cong I \times X$. Then your adjunction is just a special case of the general adjunction between the coproduct and the product: $\operatorname{Hom}(\coprod\limits_I X, Y) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(X, \prod\limits_I Y)$

The product topology on $X^I$ clearly does the job. More generally, if $I$ is a core-compact topological space, we have an adjunction between $I \times -$ and $\hom(I,-)$, called the exponential law.
